# Elasticsearch Aggregations. What are they?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-aggregation, trend

can someone please in simple sentences explain what is elasticsearch aggregation exactly?
I searched but everywhere there are some explanations about how to use it, and about syntax.
but I can't understand the reason why they exist. what is their main purpose.
what kind of query they've build for ?

I need trend tags (suggest terms in search as you type ) in my search system 
I faced elastic aggs , and I have no Idea what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know SQL, elasticsearch aggregations are kind of group by clause of elasticsearch.
You can aggregate(group by) on field you want, can have document count on that field, can also have all the documents in that group, can have nested aggs(group by).

For **suggest terms in search as you type** aggs will not work ..  you need to read about analysis document ... or read about fuzzy query in elasticsearch.

Comment: can you provide some real world examples please ?
for a beginner person .
thanks.